# Merging Arrays on non duplicated values

Tags: php, arrays

Say I have the following associative arrays, How do I combine the two to form arrays with non duplication. I have tried array merge but it does not work. Any suggestions to achieve this is highly appreciated, array unique and array combine do not work for this exercise.
//Array A

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [data_month] => Jan
            [quantity] => 123
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [data_month] => Mar
            [quantity] => 286
        )
);
```

//Array B

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [data_month] =>Jan
            [quantity] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [data_month] => Feb
            [quantity] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [data_month] => Mar
            [quantity] => 0
        )
[3] => Array
        (
            [data_month] => Apr
            [quantity] => 0
        )
[4] => Array
        (
            [data_month] => May
            [quantity] => 0
        )
);
```

//Result

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [data_month] => Jan
            [quantity] => 123
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [data_month] => Feb
            [quantity] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [data_month] => Mar
            [quantity] => 286
        )
[3] => Array
        (
            [data_month] => Apr
            [quantity] => 0
        )
[4] => Array
        (
            [data_month] => May
            [quantity] => 0
        )
);
```

Comment: have you tried anything code?

Comment: And what's the aggregation function for the quantity values? Sum? Max? Diff?

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the most efficient way of coding it, but if you assign the data_month as a key and quantity as a value to a new array, you can check if the value exists and add the quantity if it does.  Then you have to add another loop to put it back into the original format:

```
// loop through each array and assign it to a third, adding to the value if the key already exists
foreach($arr1 as $value) {
        if (isset($arr3[$value['data_month']])) {
                $arr3[$value['data_month']] = $arr3[$value['data_month']] + $value['quantity'];
        } else {
                $arr3[$value['data_month']] = $value['quantity'];
        }
}
foreach($arr2 as $value) {
        if (isset($arr3[$value['data_month']])) {
                $arr3[$value['data_month']] = $arr3[$value['data_month']] + $value['quantity'];
        } else {
                $arr3[$value['data_month']] = $value['quantity'];
        }
}

// use the key/value pairs to populate the final arrays
foreach($arr3 as $key => $value) {
        $final[] = array(
                'data_month' => $key,
                'quantity' => $value
        );
}
```